# Calculate UR10e robot payload

Tags: universal-robot, ur10

I am trying to program a pick-and-place task with a UR10e robot but I am having a problem with the payload, I am trying to move the robot as fast as possible to complete a cycle in less than 6 seconds, however, the gripper weights around 4 kg and I don't have the exact weight of the objects to pick because they are flower bouquets and their weight varies for each bouquet. Currently, I am using the following script to calculate the payload, but the measurements sometimes are not accurate enough, which triggers the robot's safety stops.

```py
wrench = force()
mass = tool_mass + wrench/9.18
set_target_payload(mass, [-0.05000, -0.05000, 0.220000], [0.016167, 0.016167, 0.016167, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000])
```

So, I am thinking about using a thread that will constantly run this script parallel to that main program and update the payload according to the forces exerted on the tool flange but I want to know if doing something like this would be safe for both the operator that could be near the robot and the robot itself taking into account I am trying to move the robot at max velocity and high accelerations or if it would be better to adjust the payload to a fixed value even if it is not 100% accurate.

Thanks in advance for the response and I will be checking if there is additional information needed :)